# Javascript getUTCDate returns "31" as day when picking 2013/04/01?

Tags: javascript, date

In javascript, by using the method getUTCDate()  a error came.

with a datepicker a chose a the date 2013/04/01, but the getUTCDate() returns 31 for the same month and year. By using the method getDate() the return number is 1. seems a bug to me but...

why does this happen?

My UTC+00 -- Portugal

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
     var dataToData = new Date();
     dataToData = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"); //ui-jquery datepicker

     var yearDpick = "";
     var monthDpick = "";
     var dayDpick = "";

     var monthaux = dataToData.getMonth() + 1;
     var dayaux2 = dataToData.getUTCDate();
     var dayaux = dataToData.getDate();
     yearDpick += dataToData.getFullYear().toString();

      if (monthaux > 9) {
           monthDpick += monthaux.toString();
           } else monthDpick += "0" + monthaux.toString();

       if (dayaux > 9) {
          dayDpick += dayaux.toString();
          } else dayDpick += "0" + dayaux.toString();



       alert(dayaux2.toString());

       alert(yearDpick+monthDpick+dayDpick);
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: Seems more likely the bug is with the datepicker, than with `getUTCDate()`, no?

Comment: You have a missing `}` in line 7. Oh, wait... silly me, you didn't provide code. `:P`

Comment: What is your timezone offset? If you are say UTC+10, then 2013-04-01T09:00:00 local time will be 2013-03-31T23:00:00Z. Note also that months are zero indexed, which might be confusing things further.

Comment: Please post code - hopefully a minimally reproducible example - and avoid begging-the-bug. It could be a bug, but normally it is just a programming error or misunderstood operation.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not living in UTC. You're probably living in UTC+xx. If you set a date with `setDate`, don't use `getUTCDate` later. Keep in mind that `new Date()` will use your local time instead of UTC if you use a string as argument.

Comment: The [time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) for Date objects is UTC. Calling `new Date()` with [zero or one argument](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) is different to calling it with [two or more arguments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1).